# SQL: use ID's in temp table to query another table

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

I have a query which loads data into a temporary table

```
SELECT * INTO #tempTable FROM Players where [reference month] = '2016-08-01'
```

I now need to use these ID's to find them in the previous month

```
SELECT ID FROM Players WHERE [reference month] = '2016-07-01' AND EXISTS 
(SELECT #tempTable.ID FROM #tempTable)
```

I have tested the `#tempTable` (SELECT * FROM #tempTable) which returns 346 records which is correct.

The above code is searching every record (1000+) in the Players table and not the specific ID's that are found in the `#tempTable`

How can I fix this query to only use the ID's found in the #tempTable?

Comment: INNER JOIN or use IN rather than EXISTS

Answer (score 3):

You may try any of the following options,

```
SELECT ID
FROM Players
WHERE [reference month] = '2016-07-01'
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT T.ID
        FROM #tempTable T
        WHERE T.ID = Players.ID
    )
```

OR

```
SELECT P.ID
FROM Players P
INNER JOIN #tempTable T
    ON  T.ID = Players.ID
WHERE P.[reference month] = '2016-07-01'
```

Comment: I went with the first option - and it worked - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT ID
FROM Players
WHERE [reference month] = '2016-07-01'
    AND ID IN (
        SELECT #tempTable.ID
        FROM #tempTable
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost close. Just missing `WHERE` clause in `EXISTS`

```
SELECT ID FROM Players WHERE [reference month] = '2016-07-01' AND EXISTS 
(SELECT T.ID FROM #tempTable T WHERE T.ID = Players.ID)
```